# Graphite, sending multiple values for same key: only one remains

Tags: graphite, statsd

I have this configuration in my Graphite:

```
# go-carbon.aggregation 
[sum_counts]
pattern = ^stats_counts.*
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

# /go-carbon.schemas
[default_1min_for_7days_and_1hour_for_5years]
pattern = .*
retentions = 1m:30d,1h:5y
```

I am sending same key different values in the **same minute**. But I see how some of them are ignored.

I was expecting the values to be `sum` as is defined in the `aggregationMethod`.

To be specific: I am sending 1 signal every 10 seconds to Graphite directly to this key:

```
stats_counts.test.monitor.remote.datapoint
```

But when I check what Graphite is storing I see that is only counting 1 signal per minute.

Is there any possibility to request Graphite to aggregate the incoming signals?

Note: we are using StatsD to aggregate these signals and it works, the problem is now we want to add several StatsD and then we need Graphite to aggregate the signals coming from different StatsD daemons.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like you mixed up storage aggregation, which happens when metric become too old according to the retention rules, with carbon-aggregator daemon which acts as proxy and does exactly what you need

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific I don't know what is the mistake I am making and how I can use the carbon-aggregator you are mention, I thought I am already using it.